# Will "Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall" keep my Win7 installation?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

Installed for eOS has an option to "Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall" - this will delete my previous Ubuntu and install eOS without touching my Win7 correct? I am okay with losing everything on the Ubuntu partitions but not the one with Win7 on it.

[image]

Here is my current setup:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: No, I don't think you should select the first option. I think 'Erase' will also erase Win7. - You should use the last more advanced option, after being sure you know what you do. -That is, the last option: 'Something else', then install elementary on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I know that it usually erases the whole disk when selecting that option -- but it seems that the installer is detecting that I already have Ubuntu and maybe want to reinstall as there is 3 options. 1. Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall. 2. Erase disk and install ElementaryOS. 3. Something else. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The elementaryOS installer is the same as that of Ubuntu 16.04. Take alook here; http://www.linuxtechi.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-with-screenshots/. I personally only use the `/` mountpoint. - Also note you don't need to remove Ubuntu. You can create a new partition for elementary and use both - beside Win7.

Comment: Thank you for editing that -- http://imgur.com/a/ldorj this is the installation options that I have.  If you're not sure about that option, in "something else" if I reformat everything to fresh /, /home, and swap same as when I initially set up Ubuntu it should work right? I'm sorry I'm so new at this whole thing -- I just thought that option in the installer might save me from messing it up. Thank you.

Comment: I asked on Ubuntu and they directed me here.

Comment: If you say on askubuntu that you are on elementary thay will guide you here. But the installer is ubuntu's. That was already asked there and should be a duplicate anyway if you ask it again on askubuntu. Look at this very detailed post: http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/47206

Comment: I'm not sure if I am the right person to test it with my basic knowledge of how this whole thing works.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. I will await your answer.

Comment: we should get an answer under [this new askubuntu question: Will “Erase Ubuntu16.10 and reinstall” keep my Win7 installation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/885711/47206)

Comment: Thank you for doing that, it is much clearer than when I asked - here or on ubuntu before.

Comment: My question was flagged as duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/q/698318/47206. The answer says to NOT use the first option, which is misleading, because of a bug that leads to whole hdd being erased (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192). I don't know if that was fixed in the elementary installer. I wouldn't risk that. So, the manual installation is preferable. Once you get that everything will be easy for you. What you should do: boot in ubuntu, install gparted, open it, take a screenshot of that, post it to see your partitions and I will try to help.

Comment: on the other hand, the bug is for trysty 14.04, it shouldn't affect Loki. But we need to be sure.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/yJ5Op - Here is my current set up.

Comment: this answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/885715/47206) was posted: but cloning the entire drive is more difficult than just creating a new partition. Also, I have posted this: [Is the ubicuity bug 1265192 affecting Loki installer?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10827/170).

Comment: Just saw your edit -- reading it now

Comment: So, using the installer should work if I read correctly.  However, just manually doing it is still recommended, correct?  I would just clone the drive as per the link however I do not own an external HDD at the moment.

Comment: I have never cloned an entire drive. Considering the amount of data that you have on your Win7 partition **you should not risk it by using the first option** without some kind of backup. Looking at your drive I see that the Linux partition is very small compared to the windows one. That is limiting the space you can use but I see no problem in replacing ubuntu with elementary if you know how to set `/` and `/home` partitions after selecting the last ("Something else") option in the installer.

Comment: I did it before when first installing Ubuntu -- what I would do is press the "-" button to remove the 3 partitions /,/home,swap and they would if I'm correct return to free space.  Then I would use the "+" button to recreate the /,/home,swap and then press the install now button. Is this correct? Linux right now is more something I'm learning so I do not have much space attributed to it, also as you can see there is not much room left on my HDD.

Comment: you do not need to remove/replace the swap partition. it will be good for elementary as it is (as well for other linuxes if you ever chose to add more). you just remove the `/` and `/home` (if you **really** don't want ubuntu anymore and if you have backed up or don't need your data there) and re-do them for elementary as you said. I don't think that the data on the home partition will be kept anyway if only `/` was to be replaced (but I have to ask for that myself: that's why I only use a single `/` partition and my home folders are on the same partition as `/` - but that's another story)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I need to sleep now, and will do this in when I wake.  Is it okay if I @ you if i have any trouble?

Comment: yes, but **you should take full responsibility**, I am just a medium user curious to find answers. there is always a risk when partitioning. backup is the only safe way. take a look at the new answers under my askubuntu question.

Comment: The reason that I want to reinstall is because this is my first time using Linux, and I installed many DE which brought along many excess packages and software which I do not require.  I would rather do a fresh install and wanted to try eOS as it looks very interesting to me, and less resource intensive for my very old machine.

Comment: Of course, I would never blame someone helping me if something was to go wrong. Thank you for everything that you have done already.  Cheers.

Comment: keep in touch with `@` on desktops use also. Never use desktops on top of each other (especially not in elementary): no matter what people say that is bad, I can confirm it.

Comment: I think I currently have 4 DE.  Very newbie mistake, I'm sure.

Comment: So if I'm reading what you said before correctly, you don't need a separate /home and / partition? If that is true, I will likely just delete both tomorrow then make a single / partition out of that space - anyway I'm really out now. will @ later. Thanks again. Have a good evening/day/afternoon. @cipricus

Comment: on the long run: buy an external drive; remove a lot of your win7 data; shrink the win7 drive to make more space for linux; create more partitions and install multiple well polished linuxes side-by-side instead of DEs on top of each other.

Comment: I use many linuxes and need to limit the number of partitions (an extended partition only supports 4) that's why I only use `/`. On the `/home` partition I will ask a question on askubuntu to clarify why that is recommended

Comment: [Why is a /home partition recommended?](http://askubuntu.com/q/885732/47206) and    [What are the pros and cons of having a separate home partition?](http://askubuntu.com/q/142695/47206)

Comment: @cipricus I got this -- I am on my new elementaryOS and i booted Win7 -- I didn't check if everything was there because I was so excited it worked but I am sure it is.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ***last*** (Something else) option.

The ***first*** option should be fine in Loki (the [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192) mentioned in my comments above should be fixed by now in 14.04 and not affect 16.04 and Loki at all, but **I cannot confirm that**). (I have posted a question on that: [Is the ubicuity bug 1265192 (or similar) affecting Loki installer?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10827/170))

**You have too many data on your drive to risk it** without full backup.

#### You should consider backup in all cases given that a lot of risk is involved in partitioning.

Considering our exchanges in comments and the links I have posted there on whether you should use or not a separate `/home` partition - and especially considering your setup:

- You can have two partitions  `/` and `/home` for elementary as you had for Ubuntu. As you said, you can remove them and create new ones as you did for Ubuntu; but you also have other options; for example, the separate `/home` partition is not at all a necessity; see below.
- If you want a separate `/home` partition; I think you said in a comment you want to get rid of your old settings; then you should not keep the ubuntu `/home` partition, but replace that too with a new one.
- In fact you *could* keep your old Ubuntu `home` partition by not deleting it and by just setting the `/home` mount-point to that partition when you install elementary, but then you would also keep the settings from your Ubuntu system in the newly installed elementary. That depends on what you need.
- You can if you want use only one single `/` partition instead of the two (after deleting those). See the pro and cons [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition). (I personally am skeptic as to the usefulness of the separate home partition; more here: [Is it safe to only have one partition (`/`) per system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/885732/47206)).
- Keep the swap partition as it is.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, keep your Ubuntu there, do not install elementary. Because you cannot upgrade elementary OS without reinstall it. I cannot stand this. So I leave elementary OS.

And if you still want to install I suggest you

1. quiting the installation go to your Ubuntu,
2. view your partition in your disk(search it on-line), and remember it,
3. Go back to install elementary
   And Choose last option
4. Erase the partitions except the /home and Windows partitions

And remember when you install a Linux distribution, no matter what distribution it is set your partitions by your self. You can get the partitions knowledge easily like [partition scheme](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/)